# JWSC WARNING skipping exception constructor ...could not find property corresponding to ctor param 'arg0' on public

Tags: java, ant, exception, weblogic11g

I am trying to convert a web service from using the version of ant that comes with weblogic (OFM 11G Release 1 (10.3.6)) to a newer, standalone version of ant (1.8.4). During the build with 1.8.4 I am receiving the following warnings which I would like to eliminated if possible. The warning occurs with all exception classes in the project. Can anyone provide a suggestion? I am new to weblogic web services.

```
[jwsc] [WARNING] skipping exception constructor for ca.bc.gov.webade.WebADEException: could not find property corresponding to ctor param 'arg0' on public WebADEException(java.lang.String,java.lang.Exception)
```

Here is the JWSC portion of the build file. The task is defined using the same paths as part of the build classpath below. The weblogic paths correspond to to WLS_HOME and MODULES_DIR environment variables as set by weblogic.

```
    <target name="jwsc" depends="compile">
    <path id="JWSCclasspath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${webade.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        <!-- Reference compiled classes rather than jar file due to issue deleting the jar file at the end of the build -->
        <pathelement path="${build.bus.dir}"/>
                    <pathelement path="{weblogic.dir}"/>
                    <fileset dir="${weblogic.dir}" >
                            <include name="*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                    <pathelement path="${weblogic.modules}" />
                    <fileset dir="${weblogic.modules}" >
                            <include name="*.jar"/>
                    </fileset>
    </path>
    <jwsc srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${deploy.dir}" classpathref="JWSCclasspath">
        <jws file="${war.path}/MapViewerServicesPortTypeImpl.java" type="JAXRPC">
            <WLHttpTransport contextPath="mapViewer" serviceUri="MapViewerWS" portName="MapViewerServicesPort"></WLHttpTransport>
        </jws>
    </jwsc>
</target>
```